# Different layout on different screen orientation without onCreate

Tags: android

I want two different layouts (one for portrait and one for landscape), but when I change the orientation, I don't want to repeat `onCreate`.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Its not about your layouts, activity is restarted when orientation is changed, so you can do is handle changes or make activity stick to single orientation

Comment: In addition to Rene's suggestions below you could also consider using a Fragment model.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when changing the orientation `onDestroy()` and right after that `onCreate()` of the `Activity` is called.

However you can avoid this: [Handling Configuration Changes Yourself](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

**EDIT:** For a different layout for portrait or landscape mode you can use two layouts in `onCreate()` and pick one based on the orientation (I know you wanted to avoid the onCreate method, but I don't think it is possible otherwise). Just check the current orientation and with `this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` act accordingly.

Maybe you can avoid using `onCreate()` and do the same thing in `onConfig` but I am not sure about that.

Comment: But I want different layout for landscape